# Validation Expression to allow email or 10 digit number

Tags: regex, validation

I have two validation scripts which work in their own right, but I now want to make a text box validate the content to either be one or the other - in this case an email address or a 10 digit number.

I have the following...

```
^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$

^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}$
```

I want to merge these into a single either/or validation expression.

Comment: Why not just run two validations? I imagine a regex covering both is going to be a mnaintenance nightmare... NB, your E-Mail validation above will break for IDNs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join two or more regex with the `|` "or" operator

```
^([a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10})$
```

Check a [test here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=m&regex=%5E%28%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%5B%5Cw%5C.-%5D%2a%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D@%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%5B%5Cw%5C.-%5D%2a%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%5C.%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%5Ba-zA-Z%5C.%5D%2a%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7C%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%7B1,10%7D%29%24&input=1231231%0Amy.test@gmail.com%0A)